# Debugging issue when parsing XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I'm trying to parse some data like this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml and came across a problem in the "loadParty" method (look in the tutorial). In the tutorial the XML looks like this:

```
<Party>
<Player>
    <Name></Name>
    <Level></Level>
    <Class></Class>
    <HP></HP>
    <MaxHP></MaxHP> 
</Player>
</Party>
```

And when parsing this, this works. But when I add some more Player tags in my xml file, and for example, remove the tag "Level":

```
<Party>
<Player>
    <Name></Name>
    <Level></Level>
    <Class></Class>
    <HP></HP>
    <MaxHP></MaxHP> 
</Player>
<Player>
    <Name></Name>
            // Level is removed here
    <Class></Class>
    <HP></HP>
    <MaxHP></MaxHP> 
</Player>
</Party>
```

Then it doesn't work. My parser is based on the same tutorial, but other variable names. Have a look at my debug screen:
It says numbers is 0x00, because I don't have a number tag there in my XML file...How can I solve this issue, because I don't want my XML to be all the same.

http://i53.tinypic.com/280kw8z.png

My XML is like:

```
   <app>
    <window ident="1" type="intro">
            <title></title>
            <subtitle></subtitle>
            <number></number>
   </window>
   <window ident="2" type="intro">
           <title></title>
           <subtitle></subtitle>
   </window>
   </app>
```

Comment: Is this the real XML you are using? I don't see a node number there!

Comment: Its the GDataXML class from Google: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/list

Comment: Yes OK, but what about the XML you want to parse, is it like that you posted in your question? What do you want to get from this call [appMember elementsForName:@"number"]?

Comment: If there is no number in my XML, its normal that its 0x00, but the code stops from there and thats the weird part that I don't understand and know how to solve it...

Comment: Why do you want to query nodes that don't exist?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get, or even better do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Because the number is in the for loop, and the for loop is for all the <window> elements in my XML, so the program is going to loop true all of the windows, but some of them don't have a number tag. There is no error message. The program just doesn't work/parse

Comment: then make a "@try @catch block" around this call. It is not possible the program just stops there.

Comment: If you watch my screenshot, I've put an NSLog on line 90,97 and they got printed out, but on line 104 it doesn't get printed out.

Comment: Then check for nil fist. if (numbers != nil && numbers.size > 0) {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

If you look at this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml then in the loadApp method you got this:

```
    // Name
NSArray *names = [partyMember elementsForName:@"Name"];
if (names.count > 0) {
    GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [names objectAtIndex:0];
    name = firstName.stringValue;
} else continue; // Remove this

// Level
NSArray *levels = [partyMember elementsForName:@"Level"];
if (levels.count > 0) {
    GDataXMLElement *firstLevel = (GDataXMLElement *) [levels objectAtIndex:0];
    level = firstLevel.stringValue.intValue;
} else continue; // Remove this
```

And the problem is the "else continue;" you need to remove this part because when he doesn't find the element in the XML, he goes to the "else" and then continue, which means he's going to go back to the start of the for loop and doesn't continue. The problem is solved if you remove the "else continue;"

Answer (score 0):

I think checking for nil first should solve your problem:

```
if (numbers != nil && numbers.size > 0) {...}
```

Comment: Ok just for clarification, your program just hangs on if(numbers.size > 0), it never gets past this line?

Comment: If I set a breakpoint on the line with number.count > 0, it runs until there. If I set a breakpoint on GDataXMLElement *firstNumber = (GDataXMLElement *) [numbers objectAtIndex:0];, it doesn't go further and I can't see anything in the debuggerr view.

Comment: GDataXMLElement *firstNumber = (GDataXMLElement *) [numbers objectAtIndex:0]; if numbers is nil you won't get there. You then say else continue; So what happens after that continue? Set a breakpoint there.